Feeding rewrites and other hints into an omnibus tactic
How do I feed rewrites that I've marked as safe into a custom tactic?

I'm trying to write shorter Coq proofs with more of the easy stuff hidden. To that end, in the script below I proved that (a + b) * (c + d) = a * c + a * d + b * c + b * d.
To that end, I wrote a tactic f, the intent of which is to make uninformative steps stand out less in the proof. I am okay with f being brittle and using every hint database, for example. I am also okay with f behaving differently over time as new rewrites get added to the database that it has access to. f probably shouldn't be exported because its behavior is too unpredictable, but I'm okay with it in a single file.
Ideally, I want f to have a happy path that finishes a goal, and a sad path that just applies simpl and some rewrites that I've explicitly marked. In the proof script below, I've tried to mark add_assoc, because rewriting according to associativity will terminate eventually, but I didn't mark add_comm because it'll just flip two things back and forth forever.
I tried using Hint Rewrite [name of theorem] as a way of shoveling additional rewrites into f, but I can't figure out how to get f to pick them up.
From Coq Require Import Setoid.

Ltac f := simpl; try easy; try intuition auto with *; try intuition eauto with *.

Lemma mul_0_r : forall a, a * 0 = 0.
Proof. f. Qed.
Hint Rewrite mul_0_r.

Lemma add_0_r : forall a, a + 0 = a.
Proof. f. Qed.
Hint Rewrite add_0_r.

(* we choose as a strategy moving all successors to the leftmost argument position *)
Lemma add_succ_r : forall a b, a + S b = S (a + b).
Proof. f. Qed.
Hint Rewrite add_succ_r.

Let add_assoc : forall a b c, a + (b + c) = a + b + c.
  intros a b c.
  induction a.
  all:f.
Qed.
Hint Rewrite add_assoc.

Lemma add_comm : forall a b, a + b = b + a.
Proof. f. induction a. f. f. rewrite IHa. f.
Qed.

Lemma four_add_swapper : forall a b c d, a + b + c + d = a + c + b + d.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction a.
  simpl.
  setoid_rewrite add_comm at 2.
  all:f.
Qed.

Lemma right_distributivity: forall b c d, b * (c + d) = b * c + b * d.
Proof.
  f. induction b. f. f. rewrite IHb. repeat rewrite add_assoc.
  rewrite four_add_swapper. f.
Qed.
Hint Rewrite right_distributivity.

Lemma six_add_swapper:
  forall x y z w v u, x + y + z + w + v + u = x + z + y + w + v + u.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction y.
  repeat rewrite add_0_r.
  f.
  repeat rewrite add_succ_r || rewrite add_assoc.
  f.
Qed.

Theorem full_distributivity:
  forall a b c d, (a + b) * (c + d) = a * c + a * d + b * c + b * d.
Proof.
  intros a b c d.
  induction a. f.
  pose right_distributivity. f.
  simpl.
  rewrite IHa.
  repeat rewrite add_assoc.
  pose six_add_swapper. f.
Qed.
Hint Rewrite full_distributivity.

```


I don't actually know, but you might check out how the ring and lia tactics do it. Yes, they are built into Coq, but Coq is free software, so you can inspect the source code and see how these tactics are implemented. Every one of your theorems can be proved with intros. ring. (once the ArithRing package is loaded), or lia. (once the Lia package is loaded).

To use rewriting hints from a hint database, you should use autorewrite (probably with the with keyword to pick a database). Here is how to tweak you example:
From Coq Require Import Setoid.

Create HintDb my_db.

#[local] Ltac f := simpl; autorewrite with my_db ; intuition eauto with *.

Lemma mul_0_r : forall a, a * 0 = 0.
Proof. eauto. Qed.
Hint Rewrite mul_0_r : my_db.

Lemma add_0_r : forall a, a + 0 = a.
Proof. f. Qed.
Hint Rewrite add_0_r : my_db.

(* we choose as a strategy moving all successors to the leftmost argument position *)
Lemma add_succ_r : forall a b, a + S b = S (a + b).
Proof. f. Qed.
Hint Rewrite add_succ_r : my_db.

Lemma add_assoc : forall a b c, a + (b + c) = a + b + c.
  intros a b c.
  induction a.
  all:f.
Qed.
Hint Rewrite add_assoc : my_db.

Lemma add_comm : forall a b, a + b = b + a.
Proof. f. induction a. f. f. rewrite IHa. f.
Qed.

Lemma four_add_swapper : forall a b c d, a + b + c + d = a + c + b + d.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction a.
  simpl.
  setoid_rewrite add_comm at 2.
  all:f.
Qed.

Lemma right_distributivity: forall b c d, b * (c + d) = b * c + b * d.
Proof.
  f. induction b. f. f. rewrite IHb. repeat rewrite add_assoc.
  rewrite four_add_swapper. f.
Qed.
Hint Rewrite right_distributivity : my_db.

Lemma six_add_swapper:
  forall x y z w v u, x + y + z + w + v + u = x + z + y + w + v + u.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction y.
  repeat rewrite add_0_r.
  f.
  repeat rewrite add_succ_r || rewrite add_assoc.
  f.
Qed.

Theorem full_distributivity:
  forall a b c d, (a + b) * (c + d) = a * c + a * d + b * c + b * d.
Proof.
  intros a b c d.
  induction a. f.
  simpl.
  rewrite IHa.
  f.
  now rewrite six_add_swapper.
Qed.
Hint Rewrite full_distributivity : my_db.

Due to the combination of using 1) a #[local] tactic and 2) a custom hint database, this should be very innocuous to the outside, at least until someone tries to define/use a database with the exact same name as yours. But even in that case there are solutions, using the new import categories (concretely you can use Require Import -(hints) Foo. to avoid importing hints from Foo).
